# Cypress save contents in response body as a Alias or variable

Tags: cypress

I use `cy.request` to create a new user. I need to get the `userID` and use it to assemble a url.

e.g.:

```
function createUser () {
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `/human/sign_in`
  }).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    const token = $('css to get the token')
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `/signups/brands`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        'authenticity_token': token,
        'name': 'some name',
        'email': 'some email'
      }
    })
  }).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    const userID = $('css to get userID') // here's the userID
  })
}
```

How to return this `userID`, and how to refer to it in the following codes?

```
describe('some feature', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    createUser()
    cy.visit(`/account/${userID}`)      // how to refer to it?
  })
})
```

I looked up the official documents. It seems `as()` could do some trick. But I couldn't find an example to use `as()` after `cy.request()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the createUser() function returns a correct `userID` for you ?

Comment: @soccerway `createUser()` will return a promise, which is what I've been confused. If return `userID` directly, it will be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do the same thing in our tests using a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html) and return the value from there.  A custom command with a return will automatically wait for the return value so you don't have to worry about async issues or the hassle of aliases.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("createUser", () {
  return cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `/human/sign_in`
  }).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    const token = $('css to get the token')
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `/signups/brands`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        'authenticity_token': token,
        'name': 'some name',
        'email': 'some email'
      }
    })
  }).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    return $('css to get userID') // here's the userID
  })
})
```

Then your test would look like this:

```
describe('some feature', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    cy.createUser().then(userId => {
      cy.visit(`/account/${userID}`)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: This is a good answer too, just be aware that the test suite may require a *single* value of `userId` across all tests, in which case you will need to call the custom command in a before and access it in an Cypress alias (`cy.wait('@userId'`).

Comment: You can use this in a `before()` and either store the `userId` in a variable outside the scope of the `before()` block, or better yet use `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("yourSessionCookie")` so you do not need to log in before each test.

Comment: You can now user Cypress's `alias()` function to do this:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is to add some return statements to your function and use `then()` within your test. (Thanks to @soccerway for suggesting this)

```js
function createUser () {
  return cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `/human/sign_in`
  }).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    const token = $('css to get the token')
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `/signups/brands`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        'authenticity_token': token,
        'name': 'some name',
        'email': 'some email'
      }
    })
  }).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body)
    const userID = $('css to get userID') // here's the userID
    return userID;
  })
}

describe('some feature', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    createUser().then(userID => {
      cy.visit(`/account/${userID}`)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Richard...  Will the above `cy.request()` example work for SSO model in Cypress ?..need to receives a token and redirect to some other url ?

Comment: In my Cypress test, I got a SSO scenario with Microsoft, getting the credentials and then system will redirect to another `url`, do you think will the above way work ? If you could reply that would be awesome, my question is here, please  ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155650/cypress-test-need-to-receive-a-valid-token-and-then-redirect-to-another-website

Comment: @soccerway, I don't know much about SSO but the pattern of this question is similar to that shown in the docs [Form Submission Redirects](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Form-Submission-Redirects) which seems to show it is possible.

Comment: The main difference is that you want to pass the token back out, whereas Cypress show using the token within `then(response => {...`, so you have to be careful of the subsequent tests which use the token firing off before the token is actually returned. I usually wrap that sort of code in a `before()` which ensures it runs ahead of anything else.

Comment: When i try to use the `Form Submission Redirects` its says parseOutMyToken is not defined.

Comment: `parseOutMyToken` is a for-example function which does the stuff you are doing with `tokenPattern`, although I don't understand your code too well but assume you have worked out the token parsing already.