# Cypress test need to receive a valid token and then redirect to another website

Tags: javascript, cypress

I would need to access a `MS website`, enter the test email, then a pop up displays, select an account and enter password. Now at this stage, receives a valid token from the `MS Website` and then system will be redirected to another `test_site`. In this scenario, how can I redirected to that `test_site` using Cypress so that I can perform testing in that test site.

Below is my Commands.js `getLoginToken()`

```
var accessToken;
Cypress.Commands.add('getLoginToken', () => { 
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url_here',
    body: {
        email: 'yourEmail',
        password: 'yourPassword'
     }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const rbody = (response.body);
      var tokenPattern = "(?i)\"access_token\":\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"";
      const authToken = rbody.access_token;
      accessToken = authToken;
      cy.log(accessToken);
      resolve(accessToken);
      return accessToken;
     })
  })

})
```

Cypress test :

```
describe('Navigate to test website and check the Home button', function(){
    before('Clear the cookies and run the test', ()=>{
        cy.clearCookies();
    }) 

    it('Verify whether the Home button is displaying in the test portal', function(){
      const newToken = cy.getLoginToken();
      cy.log(newToken);
      cy.visit(newToken);
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Could someone help me to find a way to handle the Microsoft SSO and redirect to another URL, please

Comment: Could you create a GitHub repo with a reproducible example and the steps we need to connect the site to an MS account?

Comment: @NoriSte, Thanks for that reply, I am not allowed/ authorised to share the redirect url and MS account details in GitHub or similar, anyway will check that with the team here. The complexity around 'MS SSO` is really hard, while login it need token as well as 3 more other parameters like `clientId`, `userIdentifier`, scopes. only if the above is satisfied the above will be redirected to the target url

Comment: I have tried grabbing the `token` and attach to the redirect url, its not working

Comment: Would like to know, any other easy options with any third party trusted library that will authenticate and redirect to the desired url.