# How to get a value inside cy.request() without getting "mixing up async and sync code"?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cypress

Today i'm trying to switch methods from an **Appium** test to **Cypress** test.
I've created a code using fetch before switching to Cypress that allow me to get information in a mail using some api request and get a specific value that i can use after my `fetch()` method is done.
I'm trying to implement it using Cypress (with `cy.request()`) but it seem impossible for me to do this.

My method looks like this :

```
export const getCodeFromMailcatcher= (numberAccount) => {
    const mailsubject = '<' + numberAccount + '>'
    let idMail
    let mailCorpsNumber
    cy.request('GET', 'http://mail.catcher/messages')
        .then(response => {
            let foundMail
            for (let value of response.body) {
                if (value.recipients == mailsubject) {
                    foundMail = value
                }
            }
            idMail = foundMail.id
            return cy.request('GET', 'http://mail.catcher/messages/' + idMail + '.plain')
                .then(response => {
                    mailCorpsNumber = response.body.match(/\d{6}/)[0]
                    cy.log(mailCorpsNumber) // Show value wanted
                    return mailCorpsNumber
                })
        })
}
```

I got this error :

[image: Cypress error, a bit boring]

I tried a lot of solution but i can't seem to find a good solution that's working.

Any idea to make it works ?
I don't want to make further action on any other `.then()` call after `cy.request()`

In my test, i'm calling this methode like that :

```
const value = getCodeFromMailcatcher(wantedSubject)
cy.log('value : ' + value) // is undefined
```

My current method whose working with Appium but seem to not work with Cypress because it's async :

```
export const getCodeFromMailcatcher = (numberAccount: string) => {
  const mailsubject = '<' + numberAccount + '>'
  let idMail
  let mailCorpsNumber
  return fetch('http://mail.integration.rd/messages', { method: 'GET' })
    .then(data => {
      return data.json()
    }).then(res => {
      let foundMail
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].recipients == mailsubject) {
          foundMail = res[i]
        }
      }
      idMail = foundMail.id
      return fetch('http://mail.integration.rd/messages/' + idMail + '.plain', { method: 'GET' })
    }).then(data => {
      return data.text()
    }).then(res => {
      mailCorpsNumber = res.match(/\d{6}/)[0]
      driver.pause(30000)
      return mailCorpsNumber
    }).catch(error => console.log('Error : ' + error))
}
```

Before asking, i searched on https://docs.cypress.io/, https://stackoverflow.com/ and other website about similar subject but nothing that actualy works for me.

Comment: I think your code is fine, cypress is just complaining about the `cy.log` call (for no good reason imo). Does it work if you remove that line?

Comment: Hello @Bergi, as i tried to show in my example, it's not working because the value returned is undefined. Got this on Cypress : `Message:  value : undefined` but the value into the `cy.request()` call is good.

Comment: Oh right, you must `return` the chain from `getCodeFromMailcatcher` and write `getCodeFromMailcatcher(wantedSubject).then(value => { cy.log('value : ' + value); … })`. But that's not what's causing the error message from your screenshot.

Comment: @Bergi i did that 
`getCodeFromMailcatcher(wantedSubject).then(value => { cy.log('value : ' + value) }`

It works but i can't get the value in a specific parameter like that : 
`const value = getCodeFromMailcatcher(wantedSubject)`
So except if i chain a lot of `then()`, i can't call my value anywhere.

Comment: No, you can't get that value synchronously. You can of course use `await` instead of `.then()`, but afaics that's discouraged by cypress (for no good reason).

Comment: @Bergi i tried to use async and await but it's not working, Cypress gave me an error too

Comment: @Bergi I'd caution against saying Cypress cautions against these things _for no good reason_. I'd recommend reading their documentation about _why_ Cypress behaves the way it does. It may seem anti-pattern to other automation tools, but they aren't causing errors "for no good reason" -- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Cypress-Can-Be-Simple-Sometimes

Comment: @agoff Actually I researched this just yesterday, and I haven't found any reason they give except "you shouldn't need it" and "it leads people to think that cypress returns promises, but it doesn't". It actually would work just fine, and could avoid the pyramid of doom.

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough, you can disagree with their decisions, I think I just wasn't a huge fan of how you were giving advice. To each their own :D

Comment: @Samix Have you checked out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701147/cypress-save-contents-in-response-body-as-a-alias-or-variable/53708850#53708850
 Seems like a similar problem to what you're having.

Comment: @agoff i already tried this one and it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Cypress does not "know" which value you want to yield to the next command or assertion in the test - the result of `cy.log`? Or the returned `mailCorpsNumber`? So it throws this error. I have explained this problem and solutions in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_H7EH0n9tE and in the recipe https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/9.2.0/recipes/yield-value.html

In your case, the simplest solution is to move the `cy.log` outside the callback

```js
.then(response => {
  mailCorpsNumber = response.body.match(/\d{6}/)[0]
  return mailCorpsNumber
})
.then(cy.log)
```

Comment: The solution works fine like @Bergi said, but i can't set the value in a const and use it later.
Thanks for the video !

Comment: It's a pity Cypress can't prefer an explicit return over an implict one.

Answer (score 1):

A `return` is missing in the translation from Appium function to Cypress.

```js
export const getCodeFromMailcatcher= (numberAccount) => {
    const mailsubject = '<' + numberAccount + '>'
    let idMail

    // don't need this
    // let mailCorpsNumber  

    // Line from Appium code
    // return fetch('http://mail.integration.rd/messages', { method: 'GET' })
    // ...add the same return here
    return cy.request('GET', 'http://mail.catcher/messages')
        .then(response => {
            let foundMail
            for (let value of response.body) {
                if (value.recipients == mailsubject) {
                    foundMail = value
                }
            }
            idMail = foundMail.id
            return cy.request('GET', 'http://mail.catcher/messages/' + idMail + '.plain')
                .then(response => {
                    const mailCorpsNumber = response.body.match(/\d{6}/)[0]

                    // see Gleb's answer re logging
                    //cy.log(mailCorpsNumber)

                    return mailCorpsNumber
                })
        })
}
```

Usage

```js
getCodeFromMailcatcher(myNumberAccount).then(mailCorpsNumber => ...
```